# How many times the word is used on the html page

Tags: java

I have a method that should return an integer which is the number of uses of the `searchWord` in the text of an HTML document:

```
public int searchForWord(String searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    if(this.htmlDocument == null){
        System.out.println("ERROR! Call crawl() before performing analysis on the document");
    }
    System.out.println("Searching for the word " + searchWord + "...");
    String bodyText = this.htmlDocument.body().text();
    if (bodyText.toLowerCase().contains(searchWord.toLowerCase())){
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

But my method always returns `count=1`, even if the word is used several times. I understand that the error should be obvious, but I’m stuck and I don’t see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently only checking once that the text contains the search word, so the count will always be either 0 or 1. To find the total count, keep looping using [`String#indexOf(str, fromIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) while the String can be found using the second argument that indicates the index to start searching from.

```
public int searchForWord(String searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    if(this.htmlDocument == null){
        System.out.println("ERROR! Call crawl() before performing analysis on the document");
    }
    System.out.println("Searching for the word " + searchWord + "...");
    String bodyText = this.htmlDocument.body().text();
    for(int idx = -1; (idx = bodyText.indexOf(searchWord, idx + 1)) != -1; count++);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but this does not work. I applied the FOR loop in my code and the updated method always returns zero now.

Comment: @misnomer42 Could you provide a reproducible example. It works fine for me: https://ideone.com/09B0lu

Comment: give me a few minutes please. I will check, maybe I have other bugs in my code

Comment: I understood what the problem is. The word I'm looking for (`searchword`) is lowercase. and on the HTML page it is always used with the first capital letter.

Thanks for your help again. It works!

Comment: @misnomer42 No problem.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Java docs [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

You're asking if the word you're looking for is contained in the document, which it is.

You could:

- Split the text on words (splitting it by spaces) and then count how many times it appears
- Iterate the String using [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) starting on index 0 and then from last index you found until the end of the String.
- Iterate the String using `contains` but starting from a certain index (doing this logic yourself).

I'd go for the 2nd approach as it seems like the easiest one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proposed approaches.
I will try to implement one of them

Answer (score 1):

These are only conditional statements, you aren't looping through the HTML text, therefor, if it finds the instance of searchWord in bodyText, it'll increment it, and then exit the method with a value of 1. I suggest looping through every word in the html, adding it to an array, and counting it that way using something like this:

```
char[] bodyTextA = bodyText.toCharArray();
```

Or keep it in a string array and split it by a space, or new line, or whatever criteria you have. Example of space:

```
//puts hello, i'm, your, and string into their own array slots in the array 
/split
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] split = str.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: @misnomer Maybe this is the kind of thing you are looking for this way, all the words can be found and accounted for

Comment: Thanks more for the help. This is an interesting solution. But I'm worried about poor performance when processing large documents.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is that the if statement is checking if the text contains the word and the increments your count variable. So even if it contains the word multiple time, your logic goes basically, if it contains it at all, increase count by one. You will have to rewrite your code to check for multiple occurrences of the word. There are many ways you can go about this, you could loop through the entire body text, you could split the body text into an array of words and check that, or you could remove the search word from the text each time you find it and keep checking until it no longer contains the search word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the option of splitting text into an array of words. This is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf(,) with an index for the last found word

```
public int searchForWord(String searchWord) {
    int count = 0;
    if(this.htmlDocument == null){
         System.out.println("ERROR! Call crawl() before performing analysis on the document");
    }
    System.out.println("Searching for the word " + searchWord + "...");
    String bodyText = this.htmlDocument.body().text();
    int index = 0;
    while ((index = bodyText.indexOf(searchWord, index + 1)) != -1) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! it is also a great solution.